# How to remove a preset?

Tags: modeling, rendering, saving

I have created several presets for *Sapling Tree Gen* add-on.
But now I want to delete some of the presets.
How can I do that?

[Here's a video about presets](https://youtu.be/FEkbdYd0oE4)

Comment: What OS you use?

Comment: macOS: Big Sur and High Sierra (two machines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac you can access and manage presets from

### Finder

**Go** (upper menu) hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to bring Library on the list
*Library > Application Support > Blender > 2.93 > scripts > presets*

or

**Go to Folder** <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
and paste this path directory

```
~/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.93/scripts/presets/
```

### Terminal

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Blender/2.93/scripts/presets/
```

---

Notes: In all cases change the number **2.93** to your current Blender version you use. Specifically Sapling's presets are stored in sub folder **operator > add_curve_sapling**. Difference in path for Finder and Terminal is just in representation of space character in name of *Application Support* - Terminal use back slash and space.

Comment: Thank you. That is the solution. All the best to you!

Comment: You are welcome ... one day probably would be standard to have achieve this by addons UI :)

Comment: Right. I think developers of Sapling Tree can add a  "Delete Current Preset" button... with a confirmation popup, in the current UI.

Comment: @LawrenceFletcher For sure ... try to contact them. There is always space to make things better :) Thank you